# SourceTree freezes every few seconds on windows

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree Version - 3.3.8.3848

Windows Version - 1909 (Build 18363.778)

SourceTree app freezes for few seconds even on hovering mouse pointer around in app or clicking any button.

I tried reinstalling many times but it sourcetree hangs every few seconds

I even tried this [workaround](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2093) about changing config file till the issue is same

I also tried disabling Lib2Git integration as suggested by some Reddit post still the same problem